# How can i remove the Deprecation error in sklearn(python3)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deprecation-warning

I started working on sklearn recently, i executed a command:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
```

it gave an error as:

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib.py", line 1
>      import imp
>   DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses"

Now i have no clue what to do next.. every other library like matplotlib and pandas are working just fine othr than sklearn. any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It's not actually a error, it's a *warning*... You can work safely with your code. If you still want to remove it, see my answer....

Answer (score 2):

One way would be just to update your sklearn:

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
0.22.1
```

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
```

No error as you see.

Another way is to silence a warning:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```